how to resolve stack creation issue on aws cloud formation
Im not able to create a stack on AWS cloudformation  using this code. Please suggest the changes to make so that my project can run
I tried changing the python version from 3.7 to 3.8 now it shows message

Resource handler returned message: "Layers consume more than the available size of 262144000 bytes"

i cant resolve the issue

Layers consume more than the available size of 262144000 bytes is the hard limit enforced by AWS Lambda service.

Hard limit converted to MB to Bytes 
250MB = 250 * 1024 (KB) * 1024 (Bytes) = 262144000 bytes
Reference:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html

so how do i reduce the size ?

If you can remove dependency do recude it to 250 mb else convert the lambda function to docker image
